# How to change a single column to a row in file csv with pandas python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a csv file like this :

```
Authors,Title,Link,Author Keywords
"Bennacer S.A., Sabiri K., Aaroud A., Akodadi K., Cherradi B.","A comprehensive survey on blockchain-based healthcare industry: applications and challenges","https://www.scopus.com/inward/record.uri?eid=2-s2.0-85152097785&doi=10.11591%2fijeecs.v30.i3.pp1558-1571&partnerID=40&md5=abddc224666bbc71d4bfe0a69f4d425f%22,%22Blockchain technology; Data management; Data security and privacy; Data sharing; Electronic health record; Healthcare"
```

And I want to change it to a csv file like this so that each author has his own keyswords:

```
author,keyword1,keyword2,keyword3,...
Bennacer S.A,Blockchain technology,Data management, Data security and privacy, Data sharing, Electronic health record, Healthcare
Sabiri K.,Blockchain technology,Data management, Data security and privacy, Data sharing, Electronic health record, Healthcare
```

And so on

I tried this code and I just got to eliminate the titles and the links

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("scopus.csv")

df1 = df\[\["Authors","Author Keywords"\]\]

df1
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the csv example you shared might not be set up as intended. It's still possible to address the issue but it might be worth confirming if there aren't some double quotes missing somewhere before "Blockchain" and after the url like this (just an example):

Authors,Title,Link,Author Keywords
"Bennacer S.A., Sabiri K., Aaroud A., Akodadi K., Cherradi B.","A comprehensive survey on blockchain-based healthcare industry: applications and challenges","https://www.scopus.com/inward/record.uri?eid=2-s2.0-85152097785&doi=10.11591%2fijeecs.v30.i3.pp1558-1571&partnerID=40&md5=abddc224666bbc71d4bfe0a69f4d425f%22%22","Blockchain technology; Data management; Data security and privacy; Data sharing; Electronic health record; Healthcare"

**If the csv is meant to look something like this**, then you can do:

```
df = pd.read_csv('scopus.csv', usecols=['Authors', 'Author Keywords'])  # Read file

auth_lst = [ele.strip() for ele in df['Authors'].str.split(',')[0]]  # Get list of authors
kwd_lst = [ele.strip() for ele in df['Author Keywords'].str.split(';')[0]]  # Get list of keywords
kwd_dict = {f'keyword{i+1}': kwd_lst[i] for i in range(len(keyword_lst))}  # Create a dictionary with keyword id & value combinations

auth_df = pd.DataFrame({'Author': author_lst})  # Create dataframe with authors
kw_df = pd.DataFrame([kwd_dict])  # Create dataframe with keywords

# Merge author and keyword dataframes
auth_df['dummy'] = 1
kw_df['dummy'] = 1
auth_kwd_df = auth_df.merge(kw_df, on='dummy')
auth_kwd_df.drop(columns=['dummy'], inplace=True)
```

This solution applies to the example above. If your csv file is formatted a bit differently (or if you're iterating over many such files/entries), you would need to adapt the proposed solution.

Comment: It worked thank you so much, but i have a lot of lines i just wrote a single one as an example DO I just have to make a loop so that i can apply this to all of them

Comment: Great! One thing to keep in mind is that the number of keywords might vary (if you're combining multiple such examples).